# Simple problem with Valgrind and allocation/free memory

Tags: c, valgrind

I am new to using Valgrind and I have a problem trying to interpret the results. I have a simple "linked list" problem, but Valgrind says that I have some problems in the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct str_list{
    char *str;
    struct str_list *next;
}str_list_t;

str_list_t*
split(char str[], char* sep){
    str_list_t *first = NULL;
    str_list_t *last = NULL;

    char *token = strtok(str, sep);

    while(token != NULL){
        str_list_t *new_node = (str_list_t *)malloc(sizeof(str_list_t));
        new_node->str = token;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if (first == NULL){
            first = new_node;
            last = new_node;
        }else{
            last->next = new_node;
            last = new_node;

        }
        token = strtok(NULL, sep);

        free(new_node);
    }
    return first;
}


int main(){
    char t[] = "Hello_World";
    str_list_t * test = split(t, "_");
    return 1;

}
```

and the Valgrind output is:

```
==9628== Invalid write of size 8
==9628==    at 0x1087BF: split (test.c:26)
==9628==    by 0x108828: main (test.c:40)
==9628==  Address 0x51d7048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==9628==    at 0x4C2CDDB: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==9628==    by 0x1087EB: split (test.c:32)
==9628==    by 0x108828: main (test.c:40)
==9628==  Block was alloc'd at
==9628==    at 0x4C2BBAF: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==9628==    by 0x108782: split (test.c:18)
==9628==    by 0x108828: main (test.c:40)
```

Specifically the problems are in this line:

```
last->next = new_node;
free(new_node);
str_list_t *new_node = (str_list_t *)malloc(sizeof(str_list_t));
```

Comment: you free `new_node`, and then use `last` in your next iteration of the loop.  `last` is pointing at that freed memory (`last = new_node`).  And therefore can't be used.

Comment: Since presumably you're intending for someone to actually be able to use that linked list after calling `split`, it's counterproductive to be `free`ing it at all in that function.  What I think you want is a `delete_str_list` function the client can call when they are done with it.  You are very smart to use and pay attention to the output of valgrind, by the way.  Continue to do so :)

Comment: Thanks @zzxyz. !!! So, I have to not free the new_node in the list during the execution (almost if I want to delete it for any reason), but I have to free for example before finish the main(). Right?

Comment: You free memory you allocate whenever you're done with it. If you don't free it when the program finishes then valgrind will still complain of leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve the problem making some changes in the code and adding a function that free the list nodes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct str_list{
    char *str;
    struct str_list *next;
}str_list;


str_list_t*
split(char str[] , char* sep){
    str_list_t *first = NULL;
    str_list_t *last = NULL;

    // Returns first token
    char *token = strtok(str, sep);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (first == NULL){
            /*
             * This is first
             * */
            first = (str_list_t *)malloc(sizeof(str_list_t));
            first->str = token;
            first->next = NULL;
            last = first;
        }else{
            /**
             * There are more
             * */
            last->next = (str_list_t *)malloc(sizeof(str_list_t));
            last->next->str = token;
            last->next->next = NULL;
            last = last->next;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "_");
    }
    return first;
}
void clean_str_list ( str_list_t *first ){
    /**
     * This function is used to free memory
     *
     *
     * Parameters
     * ----------
     *
     * first -> void pointer to the first element of the str_list.
     *
     * */

    str_list_t *node;

    while((node = first) != NULL){
        first = first->next;
        free(node);
    }
    node = NULL;
}
```